# In live site php file not working it show internal server error

Tags: php, server, issue-tracking

While uploading the `.php` file in server it shows

> internal server error

But it runs `.html` file. Its a shared hosting.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: check your server error logs.

Comment: provide some codes